# Token Tutorial: How to provide an address correctly to the `mintToken` function?

Tags: go-ethereum, tokens

I worked the [Token tutorial.](https://www.ethereum.org/token#central-mint) At one stage, newly minted tokens can be supplied to a `target` address. However, when I provide the address from a test account on a private net (`eth.account[1]`), I get an error:

```
> eth.accounts
["0xf134f55797c344c5894d009d2784c0f32fd74199", "0x922d2931678e0641dc7d13cb38a2f0897252b0de"]
> token2.mintToken(eth.accounts[1], 1000000)
invalid address
    at web3.js:3887:15
    at web3.js:3713:20
    at web3.js:4939:28
    at web3.js:4938:12
    at web3.js:4964:18
    at web3.js:4989:23
    at web3.js:4055:16
    at web3.js:4141:16
    at <anonymous>:1:1
```

I got the same error, when truncating the address by the prefix `0x`, as I read about somewhere else.

How else do I need to format an address to provide to a contract?

Address is valid:

```
> var isStrictAddress = function (address) {
....     return /^0x[0-9a-f]{40}$/i.test(address);
.... };
undefined
> isStrictAddress
function(address)
> isStrictAddress(eth.accounts[0])
true
```

Answer (score 5):

If you're trying to pass a *literal* address (like in the mintToken function), it must be in a string and prefixed with 0x. For instance:

```
"0x1cF35d6a2988B959ac9104404e9985C213880c83"
```

Alternatively, you can pass an address from the eth.accounts array. (Note the plural variable name - "accounts" not "account".) For instance:

```
eth.accounts[0]
```

It looks like this is the web3.js code that's throwing:

```
var inputAddressFormatter = function (address) {
    var iban = new Iban(address);
    if (iban.isValid() && iban.isDirect()) {
        return '0x' + iban.address();
    } else if (utils.isStrictAddress(address)) {
        return address;
    } else if (utils.isAddress(address)) {
        return '0x' + address;
    }
    throw new Error('invalid address');
};

...

var isStrictAddress = function (address) {
    return /^0x[0-9a-f]{40}$/i.test(address);
};
```

(isStrictAddress() should pass with the address you've given above.)

Comment: In my case, `eth.accounts[0]` returns a string and is identical to a string prefixed by `0x`. Submitting a string returns `invalid address`. But I'm submitting by `eth.accounts[0]`, which exists?!

Comment: Can you update your question with a transcript of your console session?

Comment: I added console output.

Comment: Interesting. Any chance you can add the contract code? The address *looks* valid, and seems to pass a visual check. I wonder if you have the parameters reversed? Like maybe the 1000000 is being passed to an address parameter, and confusing things?

Comment: I checked exactly that, but no that isn't the case. Its the code from the linked tutorial, extended by the `mintToken` function (without the modifier).

Comment: Added address validation.

Comment: Yup, that's interesting. You might have stumbled on a bug in your client. Are you using an up-to-date version? Try the same thing on a newer or older one just to rule that out. But I might have to duck out after that. ??

Comment: I'm using the geth-1.4.6 stable client.

Comment: Ya, maybe try 1.4.7? Or 1.4.8... just don't run 1.4.8 with the soft fork flag on a public network. :/

Comment: How do I update to the latest version? I ran `git pull origin master` but my client is still 1.4.6. Do I need to clone a new repository?

Comment: You can just download the binaries from github (https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/releases).

Comment: Ok, and if I would like to keep working with the source?

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the default account and then execute:

```
web3.eth.defaultAccount = web3.eth.accounts[0]
```

Hope this helps...!